# Hide Scrollbar in Oracle Apex Navigation Menu

Tags: browser, oracle-apex

Hopefully someone can help me here.

I'm working in Oracle Apex and have a side navigation menu which expands and shrinks. In both versions there is a visible web browser vertical scroll bar.

Is it possible to hide this but still maintain the scroll feature?

For example this sample application I found online (https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42599:1::::::) contains the same functionality but without the scrollbar present. Looks a lot cleaner and doesn't get in the way of text / icons etc.

Here is a picture to show both systems.

[image: Example of the scrollbar]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want this behaviour throuhought the application, define the below CSS code either on the page 0 or in a global CSS file.

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera*/
.t-TreeNav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/*Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.t-TreeNav {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /*IE and Edge*/
  scrollbar-width: none;  /*Firefox */
}
```